# How to merge a single array per 15 index in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a single array in my data like this :

```
["1"]
["2"]
["3"]
["4"]
["5"]
["6"]
["7"]
["8"]
["9"]
["10"]
["11"]
["12"]
["13"]
["14"]
["15"]
["16"]
```

And I wanna make combine them into 2 part.

part 1 :

```
["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"]
```

part 2 :

```
["9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16"]
```

when I combine them :

```
[["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"],["9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16"]]
```

That is enough when I just use `split` function to combine my array and make my array into double part?

***If my explanation is incomprehensible, I apologize, and you can ask me again, Thank You***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [`.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) your array into two halves, and then join them into the one array, by flattening each half using `[].concat(...half)`. See example below:

```js
const arr = [["1"], ["2"], ["3"], ["4"], ["5"], ["6"], ["7"], ["8"], ["9"], ["10"], ["11"], ["12"], ["13"], ["14"], ["15"], ["16"]];

const a = arr.slice(0, arr.length/2);
const b = arr.slice(arr.length/2);
const res = [[].concat(...a), [].concat(...b)];
console.log(res);
```

If you can support [`.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat), you can simplify `res` to be:

```
const res = [a.flat(), b.flat()];
```

Comment: This is awesome @Nick, thanks for helping, So the conclusion are first I must make a double variable to make a sign in my double array (a and b) and slice them, end for the final is I must concat my variable or flat them, right?

Comment: @LuckALip so first you obtain `a` to be: `[["1"], ["2"], ["3"], ["4"], ["5"], ["6"], ["7"], ["8"]]`, and `b` to be `[["8"], ["9"], ["10"], ["11"], ["12"], ["13"], ["14"], ["15"], ["16"]]` by using slice,  then you use `.concat()` or `.flat()` on these two halfs to flatten them (ie: remove the nested arrays)

Comment: Yes I'm understand, your solution is very easy to understand, thanks again

Answer (score 2):

```js
 const arr = [["1"], ["2"], ["3"], ["4"], ["5"], ["6"] ,["7"], ["8"], ["9"], ["10"], ["11"], ["12"], ["13"], ["14"], ["15"] ,["16"]]
 newarr = arr.flat()
 res = [newarr.splice(0,8),newarr]
 console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.prototype.flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) then split it with Array.prototype.splice. [Array.prototype.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) will consume the source array so it'll be better in comparison with Array.slice in term of performance. You'll only need to call it once. One small note is that Array.prototype.flat is only available in new browsers so if you want to support older browsers then you can use alternative solutions or polyfill mentioned in the related documentation.

```js
const arr = [["1"], ["2"], ["3"], ["4"], ["5"], ["6"], ["7"], ["8"], ["9"], ["10"], ["11"], ["12"], ["13"], ["14"], ["15"], ["16"]];

const flatArr = arr.flat();

console.log([flatArr.splice(0, flatArr.length/2), flatArr]);
```